# Download ftp file with curl without traversing parent directories

Tags: curl, ftp

I would like to download files from an ftp server. I've confirmed that I have access as I can download the files manually using Chrome to list the ftp directory contents and click on each file, downloading them one at a time. There are a lot of files, though, and I'd like to use curl to grab them all for me.

However, the ftp server is set up so that I do not have access to the `Parent`  directory, even though I do have access to the `Child` one, so the below `curl` command fails:

```
curl -u username:password "ftp://example.com/Parent/Child/file.txt" -o file.txt
```

Key excerpts from verbose (`-v`) output:

```
< 230 User logged in.
> PWD
* Entry path is '/'
> CWD Parent
< 550 Access is denied
* Server denied you to change to the given directory
curl: (9) Server denied you to change to the given directory
```

Is there any way that I can have curl change directly to the final directory instead of walking the hierarchy, to avoid it giving an error on the disallowed parent directories?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. Curl works by splitting the path on each `/` character, then issuing a `PWD` command one at a time (as you can see from the verbose output).

Simply urlencode your intermediate `/` characters with `%2f` and curl will issue the `CWD` command all at once:

```
$ curl -u username:password "ftp://example.com/Parent%2fChild/file.txt" -o file.txt

> CWD Parent/Child
< 250 CWD command successful.
```

Voilà!